# Setting Scope/Binding/this in Ember.computed.map

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I was wondering if it was possible to bind the scope of `this` inside of an `Ember.computed.map` function to be scoped to the model instance rather than the module itself.

For example, I would like to write something like:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    property1: valueWhichChangesWithModel1,
    property2: valueWhichChangesWithModel2,
    helperProperty: Ember.computed('property1', function () {
        const property = this.get('property1');
        return [whatever(property)];
    })
    mapFunction: Ember.computed.map('helperProperty', 'property2', function (value, index)  {
        return stuff(value, this.get('property2'));
    })
})
```

However, the `this.get('property2')` always fails because `this` is bound to the module, not the model object.

All kind of normal binding tricks I have tried have not given me access to the model instance, e.g. to us `bind` or `apply` in different places on the function.  I am not sure if I just didn't happen to find the right place to put it, if there is another workaround, or if this is just known to be impossible.  I could not find any references for how to approach this in Ember's documentation either.  Thanks for any advice anyone may have!

Comment: do you mean to use `DS.Model.extend` ?

Comment: @kumkanillam actually, no.  a custom data implementation is being used rather than Ember Data, so I do actually mean `Ember.Model` in this case.

Comment: @kumkanillam to further clarify, I just changed it back to Object as this is functionally what is happening.  Sorry for the confusion.